# Can I use a Clipsal amp 56/32 for a washer and electric condenser dryer

Tags: electrical

[image]Miele condenser Dryer enter image description here[image]I have a washing machine connected to clipsal amp 56/32, there are no other plugs in the laundry area. Can I connect my electric condenser dryer into the same outlet.

Comment: Pictures and the nameplate rating on the dryer would be nice and helpful.

Comment: Thank you, for your reply. I have added a photo of the name plate plate